# Sinch APN shouldSendPushNotifications never called

Tags: sinch

I can´t make Apple Push Notifications work in development mode. The shouldSendPushNotifications method is never called on the source device when the target device is in background mode. I have uploaded my APN development certificate in the Sinch Dashboard and instant messaging works if both devices are in foreground mode. I have a valid device token which I´m using for my own Push Messages. Here is my code:

```
sinCli = Sinch.clientWithApplicationKey("XXXX", applicationSecret: "XXXX", environmentHost: "sandbox.sinch.com", userId: sinchUserId)

    sinCli.delegate = self
    sinCli.setSupportMessaging(true)

    if let deviceToken = defaults.dataForKey(Globals.KEY_APN_DEVICE_TOKEN)
    {
        sinCli.setSupportPushNotifications(true)
        sinCli.registerPushNotificationDeviceToken(deviceToken, type: SINPushTypeRemote, apsEnvironment: SINAPSEnvironment.Development)
        sinCli.setPushNotificationDisplayName("MyApp")
    }

    sinCli.start()
    sinCli.startListeningOnActiveConnection()

    sinCli.messageClient().delegate = self
```

did I forget something?

Answer (score 1):

I think I need to see your swift wrapper, but it almost looks like you are setting up the client for push (not managed), and then registring the token for managed push.
When using managed push (when you upload to cert to us) shouldSendPush is never called, because Sinch takes care of the pushing, you should just get a push. What you do need is to have a push delegate https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/ios-managed-push/

Comment: I´m using the SinchService framework now instead of the SINClient and it works fine

Comment: Yes, but there is still one issue I would like to address: in my settings I can switch off push notifications but since the SinchService only works with Push Notifications enabled I have to use the SINClient if the user disables Push Notifications in the settings. This is a bit cumbersome, it would be better if I could use the SinchService for both cases.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand, and it feels like it has nothing to do with this question?